# ¿Cual es la mejor forma para encriptar una base de datos (SQLite - Android)?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlite3

Imagino dos posibles formas de encriptar una base de datos, una encriptar los datos por medio de una clase encargada de encriptar y desencriptar o algun mecanismo que lo realice automáticamente pero no estoy seguro que utilizar.

Comment: Yo uso SQLCipher : https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/

Comment: Vale la pena comprar una licencia? o la versión OpenSource es buena?

Comment: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/  opensource es la que uso, comparar con otras soluciones, no puedo ya que no he probado otra opción pero cumple su cometido.

Comment: Lo probare y te digo que tal me fue :P